# Create a pdf with Python Flask from file

Tags: python, pdf, flask, converters

I need to write a python flask service which takes in input a file (.doc or .ppt) and returns the same file converted in pdf without saving it in a folder. This service has to run on a server.

I tried with pdfkit but I've it not easy to install it on a server.
What i need is something like this:

```
def post(self):
    file = request.files['file_request']
    
    pdf = pdfkit.from_file(file, False) #or any other library to convert the file
    return send_file(
        pdf,
        mimetype='application/application/pdf',
        attachment_filename="File.pdf",
        as_attachment=True,
        cache_timeout=0
    )
```

Is it possible to do it? Could somebody help me?
Thanks